# Applescript an app to change background of notification centre in mountain lion

Tags: macos, applescript, notificationcenter

I wanted to create an app to change the background of the notification centre so applescripted it. Someone please tell me what's wrong with my code.

```
set NCBGPath to "/System/Library/CoreServices/Notification Center/Contents/Resources/"
set NCBackground to "linen.tiff"
set themeFolder to (choose folder with prompt "Choose a Theme") as text
set themePath to themeFolder & NCBackground
set posixNCPath to NCBGPath & NCBackground

set shouldCopy to false
tell application "Finder"
    if exists file themePath then set shouldCopy to true
end tell

if shouldCopy then
    do shell script "cp " & quoted form of POSIX path of themePath & space & quoted form of posixNCPath with administrator privileges
    -- you probably should correct the file permissions too as the copied file probably won't have the proper owner and stuff
else
    display dialog "Could not find the background file in the chosen folder."
end if
```

Answer (score 0):

Possibly this: "If cp detects an attempt to copy a file to itself, the copy will fail."

What happens if you change the last if statement to:

```
if shouldCopy then
    do shell script "cp " & quoted form of POSIX path of themePath & space & quoted form of NCBGPath with administrator privileges
    -- you probably should correct the file permissions too as the copied file probably won't have the proper owner and stuff
else
    display dialog "Could not find the background file in the chosen folder."
end if
```

Comment: it says /System/Library/CoreServices/Notification Center/Contents/Resources/ does not exist